# how to log data when application run on vs 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

i have an application running (c#) and (c++) on visual studio.
When the application does generate some data. i would like to know if i'm able to log the data into some excel or any format that i can look at after that.

are there any methods or any way of doing that?

as in sample code of writing it to visual studio and log the data

Comment: When you say "log data to excel", what kind of data are you interested in?

Answer (score 4):

For C# you can use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to log the data into a file. 
If you just want to see the data in the Debug console of Vs2010 you can use [System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx). 
If the application is a console app you can use Console.Writeline to see the data appear in the console. To write the data to a text file see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using "write the data to a text file " now

Answer (score 1):

you can add a third party tool called Nlog very helpful.

**http://nlog-project.org/**